# .Net Installer, Custom Actions Issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, installation

I created a .NET project that contains **multiple** Installer classes (classes that inherit from System.Configuration.Install.Installer). My goal was, to have one single assembly that contains all possible installers we would need to use in our setup projects, **but** not necessarily all of them in one single setup project.

The problem that I am experiencing is that when adding a custom action and once I select an assembly, there is no way to select a particular installer that needs to be executed. Since I am not being able to specify the installer I want to run, all installers that are found the assembly are being executed.

Is this how it works by design or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to swing your paradigm around. Create only one installer class per assembly/project but have that installer class call the relevant methods to perform your conditional installation

OR

Place each installer class in a separate assembly/project, then create a custom action for the relevant ones and use the CustomAction.Conditional property to tell the installation project which Custom action and installer class to run.
See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/025bcetc(v=vs.80).aspx